# Let $g(y) := \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}x_{n}(y)$. Find $\int_{0}^{3}g(y)dy$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f(x)$ be the function on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)\!:=\sin(\pi x/2)$. For $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$, consider the sequence $\{x_{n}(y)\}_{n\geqslant0}$ defined by $$
x_{0}(y) := y\;\;\text{ and }\;\;x_{n+1}(y)=f(x_{n}(y))\;\text{ for all }\;n\geqslant1\\\text{and let }\,g(y):=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{n}(y)\,.$$Find $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{3}g(y)\mathrm dy\,.$

**My Attempt:** Between $0$ and $3$,  $f$ has only two fixed points $0,1$, so $g$ takes only value $0,1$ in $[0,3]$. But how compute exactly $g$ in $[0,3]\,?$

Comment: You could theoretically show that the $g'(y) = 0, y \in \mathbb{R} / \{2k, k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ by simple chain rule and additive identities, and then the fact that $g'(y) \to \infty, \{y = 2k, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. However, $\max{(\sin{\dots})} = 1$, hence the function is always $1$ except for $\{y = 2k, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Answer (score 6):

When $y\in (0,2)$, $x_1(y) \in (0,1]$ and one can check that $g(y) = 1$: Indeed we have $\sin (\pi t/2)\ge t$ for all $t\in (0,1)$, thus $\{ x_n(y)\}$ is an increasing sequence for all $y\in (0,2)$ and converges to the fixed point $1$.

When $y\in (2, 3)$, $x_1(y) \in (-1, 0)$ and similarly $g(y) = -1$.

Hence $\int_0^3 g(y) dy = 1$.